# Why am I getting a Null pointer exception sending serial data to an arduino

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here is part of the stack:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at me.lorenjz.com.SerialComms.sendStuff(SerialComms.java:122)
at me.lorenjz.com.MainWindowC.actionPerformed(MainWindowC.java:82)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
```

sendStuff:

```
    public synchronized void sendStuff(String messageString){
        //System.out.print("The message being sent is:  " + messageString);
        String stupid = "button";
            try {
122:                output.write(stupid.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Here is the button that should be sending the string to "sendStuff"

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stuff has happened");
        SerialComms SC = new SerialComms();
        SC.sendStuff("Button");
    }
```

What did I do wrong here?

Loren

added code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("Started onCreate");
     MainWindowC nw = new MainWindowC();
     MixWindowTwo mwt = new MixWindowTwo();
     System.out.println("Started second window");
     SerialComms SC = new SerialComms();
        SC.initialize();

}
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger to find out what is `null` at line 122.

Comment: I think that I have a better understanding of what is going on.  In my main function (now listed above) I create an instance of SerialComms.  How do I send a message to that instance of "SC" with code in another function that is triggered by a button in another class?  I think that is what was causing the original null pointer.

Comment: I added SC to my global variables class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, `output` has not been created.